# Frequent "Connection Timeout" errors on a shared server using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have a Drupal site on a shared web host, and it's getting a lot of connection errors. It's the first time I have seen so many connection timeout errors on a server. I'm thinking it's something in the configuration settings. Non-drupal parts of the site are not giving as many connection errors.

Since this hosting provider doesn't give me access to the php.ini file, I put one at my docroot to modify the lines that I thought would be causing this:

```
memory_limit = 128M
max_execution_time = 259200
set_time_limit = 30000
```

But it didn't work. There is no improvement in the frequency of the timeout errors. Does anyone have any other ideas about this type of error?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your php.ini is actually being loaded? You can use phpinfo() to do that

Comment: Yup. The php.ini does change the figures I see in phpinfo().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the time limit on a script while your script is running. Add a called to `set_time_limit` near the top of your PHP pages to see if it helps.

Ideally you need to figure out what you actual limits are as defined by your host. A call to `phpinfo()` somewhere will let you see all the config settings that your server has in place.

Comment: The only relevant item I can find in phpinfo is mysql.connect_timeout which is set to 60. I can't tell if this is low or not.